# Testing insert methods by using factory make of Laravel with a PostgreSQL reserved id

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-testing, laravel-factory

Our Laravel app uses PostgreSQL and before we insert a register in a table we reserve the next valid id by calling PostgreSQL `nextval` function.

I want to test the `insert` method of `UserRepository`. As our database expects to receive an id I would need to generate it also in the test method that tests the `insert` method, so I use Laravel's factories `make` method like this to create a fake id:

```
$userModel = UserModel::factory()->make([
    'id' => $this->userRepository->nextValId()
    // Another solution 'id' => $this->faker->unique()->randomNumber(5)
]);
$this->userRepository->insert($userModel->toArray());
```

This might not seem too complex, but imagine I now have an `insertMany` method that inserts several users at once, and I want to test this `insertMany` method. In this case the creation with Laravel's `factory()` gets more complicated. To start off, this code wouldn't work now as the ids of all users would be the same:

```
$collection = UserModel::factory(4)->make([
    'id' => $this->userRepository->nextValId()
    // Another solution 'id' => $this->faker->unique()->randomNumber(5)
]);
$this->userRepository->insertMany($collection->toArray());
```

So I have to rewrite it like this:

```
$collection = UserModel::factory(4)->make();
$users = $collection->toArray();
$users[0]['id'] = $this->userRepository->nextValId();
$users[1]['id'] = $this->userRepository->nextValId();
$users[2]['id'] = $this->userRepository->nextValId();
$users[3]['id'] = $this->userRepository->nextValId();
$this->userRepository->insertMany($users);
```

So the question is: is there a one-liner for this use case? Is there a way to tell inside the array of the `make` that a key has to be different for every model created by the factory? (In this case, I would want `$this->userRepository->nextValId()` to act for each one of the models created.)

Of course I do not consider using Laravel's factories `create` method as it would create the register already in the database table and the later insertion would throw a duplicate key exception.

Side note: this is a fake example, not real, so it is possible that there might be a little bug. The code pasted is not proved. Mine is different, but the idea is the same as the one in the example used.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution using Laravel's factory sequences:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/database-testing#sequences

This would be the cleanest code in my opinion:

```
$collection = UserModel::factory()->count(4)->state(new Sequence(
    fn ($sequence) => ['id' => $this->userRepository->nextValId()]
    // Or this using DatabaseTransactions trait: fn ($sequence) => ['id' => $sequence->index + 1]
))->make();
$this->userRepository->insertMany($collection->toArray());
```